# "normal" time taken to reopen a question

Tags: discussion, self-answer, reopen-closed

I had a problem in the past, and posted here. Since then, I have solved it and with to add an answer explaining what I did and what was wrong. The only problem is that the question was (and is) closed. I have recently edited it to SO standards, and cast my own reopen vote. Naturally (and somewhat expected), it wasn't instant.

How long is a "normal" time or time range for a question to get enough net reopen votes to be reopened?

I'm leaving the link out because I'm not asking for people to reopen it, but to know about how long it will be before I can answer the question.

Comment: If Rachel guessed the question in question right, you can now add your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the site activity and what steps you take to try and get your question reopened, reopening a question will typically take anywhere from a few hours to a few days.

It's important to note that reopen votes start to expire at a rate of one-per-day after 4 days of no new reopen votes, and a question needs 5 reopen votes by the community to get reopened. So you have a limited window of time in which you can get your question reopened after the first reopen vote.

Normally when trying to get a question reopened, I do the following:

- Edit the question. Quite often the question was closed for a reason and could use an edit, and the edit bumps it to the front of the "active" page, so more users are likely to see it. If possible, leave a comment as well explaining your edit so users that see the closed question know it's been modified prior to the reopen attempt.
- Wait a few hours. The new [Reopen Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) is almost always empty, so any question that shows up there is likely to get handled by reviewers quickly. If a question gets 4 more Reopen votes, it will be reopened, although if it gets 3 Leave Closed votes, it will leave the Reopen queue and you need to try other means to get the question reopened.
- Ask for reopen votes in chat. Reopen votes expire after a few days if nobody else votes to reopen, so you generally want to try and draw attention to the question before they expire. Just be sure you're nice about it and be willing to accept that some other users might disagree with reopening it and argue about it.
- Ask on meta to get it reopened, and explain your reasoning in an objective way. There's nothing wrong for asking for reopen votes on meta, as the users who can vote to reopen can't be everywhere at once. Just be sure that you are objective, reasonable, and can accept users disagreeing that your question should be reopened.
- If the question still doesn't get the attention it needs after a few days and votes get close to expiring, you can also flag it for a moderator and ask them to reopen it. Be sure to include the reason why you think it should be reopened in your flag to make it easier for them to evaluate your question.

  Flagging should only be used in cases where the original question closure reason have been addressed, and the only thing preventing your question from getting reopened is lack of attention from users who can vote to reopen. It should not be used to dispute a question closure where the community has already established that the current version of the question should remain closed.

I'm assuming you're talking about reopening [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10803936/302677), which already has 3 reopen votes. You've done a nice job editing it, so have a 4th reopen vote :)

Comment: As to your last point, I don't really think that should be on the "workflow" for reopening a question anymore.  If you got that far without the question being reopened, it probably just shouldn't be reopened.  Flagging is there for situations in which the community cannot resolve the issue without a mod's assistance.  Before there was a re-open queue the non-mod process for reopening a question was hard enough that flagging was considered appropriate, but with the queue I just don't think it is anymore.  Other than that, great process, and appropriately prioritized.

Comment: Very good advice, though I think I agree with Servy about the last point.

Comment: @Servy It's an important step on smaller sites, where the active meta/chat community is much quieter and the number of users who can vote to reopen is lower. I'll update my answer a bit to clarify that you should only use a flag if your question still hasn't received the attention it needs to get reopened, and it should not be used even after other users have explained to you why your question shouldn't be reopened.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, that's the question I was talking about, and I have answered how I solved the problem. Thank you for your help.